# the Expected value of a gambling game

Tags: probability, expected-value, binomial-distribution, gambling

so here's the question:

> David runs a casino, in it, there's a game that includes flipping a coin 6 times.
>
> People pay a certain entrance fee to play this game.
>
> - if the coin lands on heads 6 times the player gets 200 dollars
> - if the coin lands on heads 5 times the player wins 50 dollars
> - if the coin lands on heads 4 times the player wins 20 dollars.
> - any other possibility the player doesn't win anything.
>
> On average David wins 187.5 dollars in one game.
>
> One day Rick comes and changes one thing in the game. after the change, David doesn't win or lose anything per each game.
>   What could've been the change that rick did?
>
> - A) decrease the entrance fee by 2 folds (entrance fee is now half of what it was)
> - B) increased the prize for 6 times heads by 12000 dollars
> - C) changed the coin to a fake coin that always lands on heads
> - D) he said after paying the entrance fee each player starts with 187.5 dollars

Comment: Nice problem. Did you try to solve it? What did you try?

Comment: i thought that the answer was c cause if it always lands on heads then the overall expected value is -200 but apparently thats wrong and the answer is A

Comment: So I think the most straightforward way to approach this problem is to consider the expected value of winnings after a game (incl. intrance fee). That is
$$
\mathbb{E} = {6 \choose 6} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^6 \cdot 200 
+  {6 \choose 5} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^6 \cdot 50
+  {6 \choose 4} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^6 \cdot 20
- \text{entrance fee}  
$$
(assuming that the coin is fair). Then modify this expression according to the different cases and see what happens to the expected value.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: Who told you that the answer is A)?  I agree with you that the answer should be C).  Matti P.'s formula for a player's expected winnings  in dollars gives $12.5-\text{entrance fee}$.  This must be $-187.5$ dollars, the negative of the expected winnings of the casino's proprietor.  The entrance fee is therefore $\$200$, and C) is then the only one of the four alternatives that reduces the casino's proprietor's expected winnings to zero.